# What determines the operating point of an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet

Let's say I have the following 2-stage op-amp:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/aVvCqHt.png]

The DC transfer is as such:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/SNrNm5L.png]

I would like the slope to be steeper and the center point to be at 0mV input. What should I be changing? In other words, what are the factors affecting the DC operating point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The input voltages need to be setup differently. You have one side increase while the other side stays the same. That goes against the entire point of a differential op-amp. You need the input to have V- go down while V+ go up simultaneously. That's why you're getting the weird knee in the output.
2. To make the line ramp steeper, the fastest/easiest way to do that with this op amp is to increase the current flow through your current source. This will source more current in differential pair and the common-source amplifier stages because you've got that current being mirrored through the pmos's. If you can change the dimensions on the transistors (length and width of the channel region), then you have more knobs to play with.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please elaborate on the first point? Which side remains constant? I thought putting the nodes vin+ and vin- on opposite sides of voltage source Vin is sufficient.

Comment: Your V- is connected directly to VAR which is at 0.9V. VAR is connected directly to gnd. Together that means that V- is **always** at 9V. A differential amplifier works properly when both V- and V+ go in opposite directions around the DC operating point. You likely need to put two Vin's into the circuit. One the way you have it and the other swap the polarity and connect it between VAR and V-. In that way, when you perform a DC sweep, both V- goes down while V+ goes up. Right now you have V- stay at 0.9 while V+ goes up.